# Law of gravitation

Tags: newtonian-gravity

How can I prove the Newton's Law of Gravitation wrong?
I saw 2-3 videos but could not understand.

What are the flaws that Einstein came up with in Newton's Law of Gravitation?

Comment: dont get me wrong, but I believe you wont be able to prove Newton wrong just by watching 2 or 3 videos. After all, it took humanity several centuries of intense theoretical and experimental work to do so.

Comment: @qftishard - you could watch the videos while standing near a very heavy object and see if they appear to be running fast

Comment: Is it Newton's laws or Einstein you want to disprove? If Newton, why do you care about Einstein?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are [three classic tests of general relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tests_of_general_relativity#Classical_tests):

1. the anomalous precession of Mercury's orbit
2. the deflection of light by the Sun
3. the gravitational redshift of light

Newton's theory predicts zero precession in test (1) and zero redshift in test (3). For test (2) Newton's theory predicts a deflection half the size of the prediction in general relativity.

The [anomalous precession of Mercury](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/26408/what-did-general-relativity-clarify-about-mercury) had already been measured when Einstein formulated GR, so that was a retrodiction. The prediction of the deflection of light was [confirmed by Eddington in 1919](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_Eddington#Relativity) and the gravitational redshift was [measured by Pound and Rebka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound%E2%80%93Rebka_experiment) in 1960.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, one more test will be the gravitational wave from binary, supernovae as well as supermass black hole.

Answer (score 0):

You can also read about the test of 'frame dragging', which is predicted by General Relativity and not Newtonian gravity, confirmed by [Gravity Probe B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_Probe_B).  Also, Newton's law of gravity is not so much 'wrong' as it is 'incomplete' (General Relativity reduces to Newtons law in the case of low energy/speeds).