# Gravitional Force of Mercury in General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, planets, perturbation-theory, solar-system, post-newtonian

I have been searching everywhere for the first order GR  term that describes the gravitational force of a mass.

Could someone kindly show me the term that describes this?

Comment: I guess, you refer to PostNewton  expansion. Nevertheless I don't know what you mean exactly with first order GR-term ? What is the quantity it should  be first order of ? It would be also very useful to which metric (Schwarzschild?)  you refer to.

Comment: There are various links given in https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/814/123208 I won't vote to close this question as a duplicate of that one because most of the answers there are link-only answers, although one answer does give a brief sketch of how to calculate the precession.

Answer (score 1):

Look up the term "precession of the perehelion of Mercury's orbit" in any general relativity text.

The term "gravitational force" is a thorny one in general relativity, and it does not map well to the formalism of the theory, but as mentioned in the comments, the Post-Newtonian expansion is the simplest way to apply that concept.