# Planar Mercury Orbit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, orbital-motion, planets, solar-system

Recently we had an exercise about the precession of Mercurys perihelion. It went like this:

Using the Schwarzschild-solution of Einsteins field-equations, we can derive the Lagrangian for a test particle (Mercury) in the gravity-field of a much more massive object (Sun):
$$
L=\frac{GM}{2}[(1-\frac{2 GM}{r c^2}) c^2 t^2-(1-\frac{2 GM}{r c^2}) ^{-1} r^2-r^2 \dot \theta^2-r ^2\dot \phi^2 \sin^2(\theta)]
$$
Using the Euler-Lagrange equations led us to the equations of motion. And for $\theta$ we got
$$ 
\frac{d}{d\tau}(r^2 \dot \theta)=r^2 \dot \phi^2 \sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)
$$
From here we needed to show that Mercurys orbital motion can take place in a single plane by assuming that at $\tau=0$ we have $\theta(\tau=0)=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\dot \theta(\tau=0)=0$. Obviously we have
$$
\frac{d}{d\tau}(r^2\dot \theta)|_{\tau=0}=2 \dot r r \dot \theta+r^2 \ddot \theta|_{\tau=0}=0
$$
however, I fail to understand how from there it follows that $\theta(\tau)=\frac{\pi}{2}$. Can someone on here please explain to me how we can conclude from this initial condition that the orbit is planar? I would be interested in the mathematic behind that, so feel free to write down formula.

Comment: A good answer is already found in the pdf linked in this answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/878

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure why you are using the E-L equations, when general relativity tells us to use the geodesic equation
$$ \ddot x ^a = - \Gamma^a_{bc} \dot x^b \dot x^c
$$
The $\theta$-component (2-component) of the geodesic equation
uses the Christoffel symbols ,
$$ \Gamma^2_{21} = \Gamma^2_{12} = r^{-2}, \ \ \ \Gamma^2_{33} = -\sin\theta\cos\theta
$$
giving
$$ \ddot \theta = \frac 2 r \dot r \dot \theta - \cos \theta \sin \theta \dot \phi^2
$$
So that checks with what you have. Then the missing argument is that an orbit initially in the plane $\theta=\pi/2$ with $\dot \theta =0$ will have $\ddot \theta =0$, and will remain in this plane.